# xPage with multiple datasources has the second datasource always opened in edit mode

Tags: xpages

I have an xPage with 2 datasources. I open the page and the first datasource is readonly, while the second datasource is in edit mode. Adding ignoreRequestParms=true seems to cause this behavior, but its the only way that the document will save to a different datasource.

I have found this link that someone has found similar behavior.
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/7756aedc25e6d81285256324005ac76c/5e2f855ea18ff802852576e3007c34f2?OpenDocument

There is something going on that I don't understand. If someone could explain this to me I would appreciate it.

Here is the code for the data source and the fields in the tab panel

```
<xp:dominoDocument var="document2" action="createDocument"
        formName="software" ignoreRequestParams="true">
    </xp:dominoDocument>

<xp:tabbedPanel id="tabbedPanel1">
    <xp:tabPanel id="tabPanel1" label="Checklist Items">
        <xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1" layout="pageDirection"
            value="#{document1.checklist}">
            <xp:selectItems>
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dbName = new     Array("","");
var Rep = @Unique(@DbColumn(dbName,"checklistitems",3));
Rep}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:selectItems>
        </xp:checkBoxGroup>
    </xp:tabPanel>
    <xp:tabPanel label="Software" id="tabPanel2">



        <xp:button value="Edit Software list" id="button1">

        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"  refreshId="panelsoft">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="edit"
                    var="document2">
                </xp:changeDocumentMode>
            </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
        <xp:button value="Save Software list" id="button2">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelsoft">
                <xp:this.action>

                    <xp:actionGroup>



                        <xp:modifyField name="uid"
                            value="#{javascript:document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()}"
                            var="document2">
                        </xp:modifyField>

                    <xp:executeScript script="#{javascript:document2.save()}">
                        </xp:executeScript></xp:actionGroup>
                </xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:br></xp:br>

        <xp:panel id="panelsoft"><xp:table rendered="#{javascript:document2.isEditable()}"><xp:tr><xp:td><xp:br></xp:br>
                    Software Name
                </xp:td>
                <xp:td>
                    <xp:inputText id="inputText1"
                        style="width:300px" value="#{document2.Softwarename}">
                    </xp:inputText></xp:td>
            </xp:tr>
            <xp:tr>
                <xp:td></xp:td>
                <xp:td></xp:td>
            </xp:tr>
        </xp:table>
        <xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:pager partialRefresh="true"
                    layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
                </xp:pager>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:this.data>
                <xp:dominoView var="view2" viewName="CustomSoftware"
                    categoryFilter="#{javascript:document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()}">
                </xp:dominoView>
            </xp:this.data>
            <xp:viewColumn columnName="uid" id="viewColumn1">
                <xp:viewColumnHeader value="uid"
                    id="viewColumnHeader1">
                </xp:viewColumnHeader>
            </xp:viewColumn>
            <xp:viewColumn columnName="Softwarename"
                id="viewColumn2">
                <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Software Name"
                    id="viewColumnHeader2">
                </xp:viewColumnHeader>
            </xp:viewColumn>
            <xp:viewColumn columnName="comments" id="viewColumn3">
                <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Comments"
                    id="viewColumnHeader3">
                </xp:viewColumnHeader>
            </xp:viewColumn>
        </xp:viewPanel>

        </xp:panel>

        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:br></xp:br>

        <xp:br></xp:br>



        <xp:br></xp:br>




        <xp:br></xp:br>

        <xp:panel>

        </xp:panel>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
    </xp:tabPanel>
</xp:tabbedPanel>
```

Comment: Please update the question with your data source definitions

Comment: I assume you're setting `action` to `openDocument` on the second data source? As Per mentions, posting your source code will help in troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: Does your second datasource define UNID? If not, it will always compose new document, so in Edit mode.

Comment: Frantisek - I define the UNID of the "parent" document as a field on the second document. If thats what you are asking.

Comment: @PatrickSawyer you need to provide the data source definition for document1 or it's going to be impossible to solve this. document2 is created by your data source definition, so unless document1 has action="openDocument", you're creating two documents and despite ignoreRequestParms, they'll both be in edit mode and be basically unrelated. Have you tried setting action="openDocument" for document2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `action` is set to `createDocument` (which you could omit, since that's the default value), this causes a new document to be created in memory. This is why the document is in edit mode: you're composing a new record. If you don't want to create a new document, then change the `action` attribute to one of the other options: `openDocument` or `editDocument`. Either of these require that the `documentId` attribute be set as well, because the data source needs to know *which* document you wish to, respectively, open or edit.

If you omit the `ignoreRequestParams` attribute, then this data source *doesn't* ignore the URL request parameters. Instead, it looks for parameters named `databaseName`, `formName`, `documentId`, and `action`. If any of these parameters are included in the URL, the value of each overrides what is defined on the data source. This is why if you open an instance of `document1`, but don't set `ignoreRequestParams` on `document2`, then *both* documents will have the same mode (read/edit): because *neither* data source is ignoring the URL, so *both* data sources are doing what the URL is telling them to.

Generally, when defining multiple data sources on the same XPage, you'll have one that can be considered the "primary" data source; any other data has some relationship to that data, but the primary data is the user's context for viewing all the data on that page. So you **want** that data source to respect URL parameters to allow navigation (from a Data View, View Panel, Repeat, etc.) to be able to indicate which document is being opened, and in what mode. But all data sources *related* to that document should explicitly specify what data they're bound to, and the action being taken on that data, and use `ignoreRequestParams` to ensure that the URL doesn't override this information.

Comment: OK, thanks for taking the time to go into the detail on this one.

Comment: Awesome. I had one XPage with a main document that needed to have four other Notes document for storing attachments. I was having terrible problems with rep/saves and with all attachments ending up attached to the main and all four other documents. Lifesaving!