# Xpage xe:Dialog box is edit previous create document

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a custom control that create a new document through ext-lib dialog box that work fine. However when the action is performed the second time it edit the document instead of creating a new document. The datasource is set to create document.

Comment: Bob, did my answer help you?

Comment: Bob, if my answer helped please feel free to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do two things with the 2nd datasource. First was to set ignoreRequestParams to true 
and then set the scope to request. These are both in the properties of the data.

`<xp:dominoDocument var="document2" formName="software" ignoreRequestParams="true" scope="request">
</xp:dominoDocument>`

I had a dialog that brings up a form with a view and unless I changed the scope to "request" I would be adding/editing multiple documents at the same time.

Here is some data on scoped variables
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/xpages-scoped-variables.htm
My problem was the item was staying in memory too long.

I asked a similar question
[xPage with multiple datasources has the second datasource always opened in edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848253/xpage-with-multiple-datasources-has-the-second-datasource-always-opened-in-edit/16894793#16894793)

Comment: It might help to include sample code, demonstrating scope="request", since one only gets access to that by delving into the data properties under all properties, rather than via the setup of the data sources on the properties tab of the XPage or custom control.

Comment: this is a very common question.  Patrick does have the right answer - set the document source to requestScope so it's not retained longer then necessary.