# Prevent replication or save conflicts in XPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I am maintaining an XPage application that has started creating multiple replication or save conflict documents BEFORE the initial document is saved.  How can this be happening and how can it be prevented?

Users create a Contract in XPages application and have not yet saved the document so no other user should be able to see it, but when they save anything from 3 to 10 duplicates are created.  It also appears to happen at random, that is at random times for random users.  When I go into the core Notes database I can see them in an example shown below.

[image]

Here is the only refernce to a document datasource I can find.

```
<xp:this.data>
   <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Contract"   computeWithForm="both">
      <xp:this.postSaveDocument>
          ...........
      </xp:this.postSaveDocument>
   </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

Comment: Show us some code - specifically your data sources as Paul mentions.

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten. The code is quite extensive and I will have to find a few specific examples to post up.  I am not from an XPages Notes background so please bear with me

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten.  I have added the only datasource I can find

Comment: I think we are going to need more code for this. If the document is saving before the user clicks save then you have some code that is executing a save during some event, if that is the case I could see some situations where this could cause a problem.

Comment: @PatrickSawyer.  Yes Patrick.  I am no expert in XPages but i feel this one is a bit of a mystery

Comment: Any chance you can post more of the code then?

Answer (score 3):

The most typical way multiple save conflicts are created for new documents is if the XPage has multiple dominoDocument datasources on the page and using a Button of type Submit or using the Save Data Sources simple action.

If datasources do not have ignoreRequestParams="true", all data sources are editing the same document, regardless of any other properties defined for the individual datasources.

The Save Data Sources simple action, as its name implies, saves all datasources on the page. However, a button of type Submit will submit the form, which tells the server to also save all datasources, not necessarily restrict functionality to any SSJS defined in the event.

Comment: Please bear with me as I am not from a Notes and Xpages background.  When you say datasources I take it you mean if there are multiple text elements on the Xpage that are set to different fields on the notes document?  If that is what you mean then yes there are numerous text elements set to different notes document fields and there are several tabs on the Xpage too

Comment: No, the fields will be fine. It's if you have multiple dominoDocument datasources on the page. By default they take their settings (database, form, create/edit/open action) from the current URL. ignoreRequestParams="true" for a dominoDocument will allow you to override loading the settings from the URL. So if you have multiple dominoDocument datasources, all but one should have ignoreRequestParams="true"

Comment: Tim Tripcony gave a great explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848253/xpage-with-multiple-datasources-has-the-second-datasource-always-opened-in-edit

Comment: Thanks for prompt repsonses.  So by data source do you mean the actual database document being created for the Contract? (the Xpages app is all about Contracts)  For example document1?

Comment: Performed a complete file search in project for ignoreRequestParams= and there are none found!!!

Comment: Any sp:dominoDocument, e.g. <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Contact" action="createDocument"></xp:dominoDocument>. From your search, all such dominoDocument datasources are retrieving their settings from the URL. So if you have more than one datasource on a page, they will be pointing to the same datasource on the page.

Comment: I just added the only data source reference I found in code to my original post

Comment: If your postSave contains any .save that would explain it. Or are there agents that do onCreate/Change?

Comment: If you're new to XPages I would suggestion you check out my site at NotesIn9.com.  It has 150+ free video tips on XPages Development. Also -  If you posted some code we could probably help you better.  What we mean by dataSource is a document or view typically.  For instance if you have multiple custom controls and each is bound to the same document then that might cause this problem.